# Getting 'NA' when calculating statistical summary in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column from Factor to numeric so I can then run statistical summary (mean, median, max, min). However I keep getting NA when running any of the statistics for this column.
Before running any conversion code, if I run `str()`,

the type is 'hms' num [1:5860776] 00:40:56 01:08:32 00:07:19......

I tried the following code

```
all_trips$ride_length <- as.numeric(as.character(all_trips$ride_length))
```

and  `is.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)` reads TRUE

when I then run `str()` I get

num [1:5860776] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ....

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the `as.character` and directly use `as.numeric`

Comment: @akrun Please post your comment as an answer, so it can be chosen as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.character` converts to `character` class from `hms` (where the storage mode is `numeric`),

```
> mode(hms::as_hms("12:34:56"))
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(hms::as_hms("12:34:56"))
[1] "double"
> class(hms::as_hms("12:34:56"))
[1] "hms"      "difftime"
```

and thus when we coerce to numeric with `as.numeric` from `as.character`, it returns NA as there are characters (`:`)

```
library(magrittr)
hms::as_hms("12:34:56") %>%
   as.character %>% 
   as.numeric
[1] NA
 hms::as_hms("12:34:56") %>%
   as.numeric
[1] 45296
```

Comment: I ran the the code as follows ```all_trips$ride_length <- as.numeric(all_trips$ride_length) ```  and now showing ```$ ride_length       : num [1:5860776] 2456 4112 439 5406``` however mean, median, max is still showing as NA

Comment: @bNHa not clear.  If it is based on the numeric column, it should get the value,  perhaps you have some NA elements, use `na.rm = TRUE`